# React: Pass through props on wrapper/convenience components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

### What I have

Take the following `Icon` component, which is meant to take an `icon='star'` and render the appropriate SVG.

It looks something ike this currently:

```
import React from "react";

export type IconType = 'star' | 'portfolio' | 'contact';
export type IconSize = 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg';

interface IconProps {
    icon: IconType,
    size?: IconSize,
}

const iconPaths: Record<IconType, JSX.Element> = {
    star: (<path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth={2} d="M11.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.519 4.674a1 1 0 00.95.69h4.915c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-3.976 2.888a1 1 0 00-.363 1.118l1.518 4.674c.3.922-.755 1.688-1.538 1.118l-3.976-2.888a1 1 0 00-1.176 0l-3.976 2.888c-.783.57-1.838-.197-1.538-1.118l1.518-4.674a1 1 0 00-.363-1.118l-3.976-2.888c-.784-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h4.914a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.519-4.674z" />),
    portfolio: (<path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth={2} d="M8 13v-1m4 1v-3m4 3V8M8 21l4-4 4 4M3 4h18M4 4h16v12a1 1 0 01-1 1H5a1 1 0 01-1-1V4z" />),
    contact: (<path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth={2} d="M3 8l7.89 5.26a2 2 0 002.22 0L21 8M5 19h14a2 2 0 002-2V7a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v10a2 2 0 002 2z" />),
}

const sizeClasses: Record<IconSize, string> = {
    sm: 'w-6 h-6',
    md: 'w-12 h-12',
    lg: 'w-20 h-20',
}

const Icon: React.FC<IconProps> = ({
    icon,
    size,
}) => {
    const path = iconPaths[icon];
    const sizeClass = size ? sizeClasses[size] : '';

    return (
        <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            className={`${ sizeClass } block mx-auto`}
            fill="none"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            stroke="currentColor"
        >
            { path }
        </svg>  
    );
};

export default Icon;
```

**But I don't like that.**

- It imposes a specific `className` on the svg.
- It doesn't allow the user to modify the svg as they please.
- It seems a bit inflexible.

### What I would Like

I would like to be able to use this icon in a way that simply hides the paths, but leaves the rest to me. Something like this:

```
<Icon icon="star" className={/* whatever I want */} otherAttributes="..." />
```

Where any other props would be forwarded to that svg. How can I just allow my `IconProps` interface to accept anything that could be put on an `svg`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the spread operator for your `otherAttributes`

```
const Icon: React.FC<IconProps> = ({
    icon,
    size,
    ...otherAttributes  // <- here
}) => {
   ...
    return (
        <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            {...otherAttributes}     // and here
        >
            { path }
        </svg>  
    );
};
```